# Ошибка: Нестандартный синтаксис; используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Выдаёт ошибку, указывая на `boost::thread`

> нестандартный синтаксис; используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член`

Что нужно исправить? Если указать тупо `&readFile`, появится другая ошибка

> &: недопустимая операция с выражением привязанной функции-члена

```
class Service {
public:
    void readFile() {...};
    void sum() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            threads.push_back(boost::thread(readFile));
        }
    }
private:
    vector<boost::thread> threads;
};
```

Comment: и ещё один комментарий: не используйте перевод сообщений компилятора. Так вы сужаете область поисков в разы. Англоязычные сообщения позволят искать ответы более оперативно.

Comment: `readFile` - функция-**член класса**. Так что как минимум, нужно указать этот факт... а как максимум, ну передали вы адрес - а *для какого объекта* ей вызываться? У нее же есть скрытый параметр `this` - откуда `thread` знает, что передавать `readFile`?

Comment: @user1056837 Ну, например, у меня VC++ 2015 диагностику выдает по-русски :) Так что это может быть вполне не перевод...